# Getting a 404 error after configuring a CNAME alias for a subdomain

Tags: 404, cname

For my domain, I am using afraid.org's free dns service, and hostinger's web hosting.

I want to point a subdomain called `lanparty`. I have created a CNAME for it in freedns. In freedns service's dashboard, I have added the CNAME entries and in hostinger control panel as well but it's forwarding me to a 404 hostinger page.

Freedns settings:
[image: The freedns settings]

Hostinger Settings:
[image: Hostinger settings]

Comment: Have you tried adding a full stop (`.`) to the end of the destination?

Comment: If I add (`.`) to the end of destination in the freedns settings it throws me `this is not a valid address`

Comment: Tried using A record lanparty to IP rather than a cname?

Comment: developer.test is on hostinger?

Comment: developet-test.w.pw link shows no website, just a note that this site is not developed. Coukd this be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that you managed to configure the CNAME correctly.   You can test it by using `ping` and ensuring that both host names report the same IP address.

```
$ ping developer-test.w.pw
PING developer-test.w.pw (31.170.165.131) 56(84) bytes of data.

$ ping lanparty.lsaciasi.ro
PING lanparty.lsaciasi.ro (31.170.164.32) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Right now they are not resolving to the same IP for me, but my guess is that they were when you took the screenshots.

The 404 error probably indicates that the destination machine is not configured to serve content for the domain name that you are pointing at it.   You would need to modify the webserver configuration of that machine and at a `virtualhost` configuration for your new subdomain.

Comment: Yes, correct, +1, same happens if you point any CNAME to gitlab/tumblr etc, but had not configured gitlab/tumblr to receive that subdomain. Gitlab/tumblr just shows 404 page.